# -[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000243d50 (lldb)

Tags: swift, swift3

I finished migrating my application to swift3 but this section keeps yielding is causing problems.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    self.navigationItem.title = artworkTitle


    let title = "<center><span style=\"font-size: 17px;font-weight:lighter;font-family:Avenir-Book;\">" + artworkCaption + "</span></center>"
    artworkImageView.image = UIImage(named: artworkImagePath)

    artworkCaptionView.attributedText = title.html2AttStr
}
```

Important Console Parts

> -[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000243d50
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

```
extension String
{
    var html2AttStr:NSAttributedString
    {
        let contents: NSMutableAttributedString?



    do {
        let attrTextStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        attrTextStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        contents = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch _ {
        contents = nil
    }
```

Console

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b70934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ad7521e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b778f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b68ec15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b68e798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114565953 -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1329
6   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114566f15 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 22
7   UIFoundation                        0x00000001144fd45c _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 5779
8   UIFoundation                        0x00000001144fbd35 -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 115
9   pg                                  0x000000010a39fe1d _TTOFCSo25NSMutableAttributedStringcfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S_ + 173
10  pg                                  0x000000010a39fba4 _TFCSo25NSMutableAttributedStringCfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S_ + 100
11  pg                                  0x000000010a39f96a _TFE2pgSSg11html2AttStrCSo18NSAttributedString + 458
12  pg                                  0x000000010a3a901d _TFC2pg21ViewControllerArtwork14viewWillAppearfSbT_ + 1197
13  pg                                  0x000000010a3a90b1 _TToFC2pg21ViewControllerArtwork14viewWillAppearfSbT_ + 49
14  UIKit                               0x000000010c642de3 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 692
15  UIKit                               0x000000010c6434f3 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147
16  UIKit                               0x000000010c67e1a3 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 890
17  UIKit                               0x000000010c67f0b9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
18  UIKit                               0x000000010c68019b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
19  UIKit                               0x000000010c8771b7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
20  UIKit                               0x000000010c560344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c312cdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c3067a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c30661e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c29462c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c2c1713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
26  UIKit                               0x000000010c495067 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 206
27  UIKit                               0x000000010cca4b30 __handleEventQueue + 5672
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b6ae311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b69359c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b692a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b692494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
32  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111084a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
33  UIKit                               0x000000010c49bf34 UIApplicationMain + 159
34  pg                                  0x000000010a3acaaf main + 111
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011233668d start + 1
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: If you have code to share with us, please don't post it as image. You can add it to your post and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: and post all relevant code, it is hard to say what's going on here without more context

Comment: Post the code of the `html2AttStr`  extension. The seems to be there.

Comment: What kind of silliness is this? `let title = "<center><span style=\"font-size: 17px;font-weight:lighter;font-family:Avenir-Book;\">" + artworkCaption + "</span></center>"` That is not how to make an attributed string. Do not form HTML and turn it into an attributed string. Form an actual attributed string!

Comment: It's not my code and I'm a beginner with no one to help me and this has to be fixed in two days. I honestly just need to talk it through with someone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I remember [reading on Apple's Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39) that if you get unrecognized selector errors, it means that the auto-wrapping of Swift structs are causing issues. Most likely it is wrapping `String.Encoding` instead of converting it to an `NSNumber` (what the Objective-C code behind `NSMutableAttributedString` is expecting).

Try replacing `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8` with `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`